# Handle memory leak dynamically

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, runtime, out-of-memory

I know there are many discussions about memory leak/ handling memory leaks in android apps, but can it handled dynamically.

I just got this question in one of my interview. The question was

> How to detect memory leak when application is running on user's device and save the data before crash(OutOfMemoryError) .

I can guess till a BaseActivity, something like just make one BaseActivity for all Activities and save the data in onStop().

I also can guess to extend [Error](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Error.html) class in the BaseActivity, but unfortunately java does not supports Multiple Inheritance and also there is no particular method in [Error](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Error.html) class to detect any errors dynamically AFAIK.

I might wrong in above cases.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the same approach as Leakcanary did. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ#how-does-it-work).

In short, they are creating weak references between objects.  After GC they are checking if the reference is being cleared. If not they are dumping heap, and analyzing dump. Analyzer computes the shortest strong reference path to the GC Roots to determine if there is a leak, and then builds the chain of references causing the leak. In that moment if leak is there you can save all data that you need.

Problem is that if you want to save all data you need to do all of this on main thread. Otherwise, app can be closed, data can be lost etc.

Comment: Its really a good technique. But can you clear me, how a weak references helped here to determine the leak ?

Comment: It's not helping you find a leak, it's helping you not to create a new one. If you have a weak reference to an object, that object will be removed by GC. So that is the only secure way to keep track of the object, and not interfere with garbage collection of those objects. 
To see if some object is leaked you need to track its lifecycle. For example, if `onDestroy()` is called in Activity, there is no reason for that activity to be kept in memory. So if there is a strong reference to that activity in some object, then that object is leaking memory.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :)